# Maven Unresolved Reference when using version from property

Tags: java, maven, kotlin

I have a maven project `project A` that has a dependency on a different maven project `project B`. I publish `Project B` as two jars, one with the regular class files and one for its tests (I need to re-use some componenents). Maven has a [plug-in for this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html).

The `pom.xml` for `project A` looks like this:

```xml
<properties>
    <project-B.version>abcd123</project-B.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>group-id-project-B</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-B</artifactId>
        <version>${project-B.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group-id-project-B</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-B</artifactId>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <version>${project-B.version}</version> <!--  Doesn't work!   -->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Somehow, both my IDE (IntelliJ) and `mvn` CLI are unable to compile this and both give an `unresolved reference` in my test classes (where I re-use test files from `project B`).

If, however, I replace `${project-B.version}` with `abcd123` in the `test-jar` dependency everything loads fine. I can't make any sense of this as to why `mvn` doesn't like me to use a variable in `properties`? This behaviour is consistent between my IDE and mvn cli.

For what it's worth, this is the output for `project B` when I use `mvn dependency:list`

```
group-id-project-B:project-B:test-jar:tests:abcd123:test
group-id-project-B:project-B:jar:tests:abcd123:compile
```

And the rest of my `pom`:

```
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>

    </build>
```

is there a bug in maven or am I missing something?

Edit:
I use `mvn clean install` and the truncated output is:

```
[INFO] --- kotlin-maven-plugin:1.3.72:test-compile (test-compile) @ optimization-engine-service ---
[ERROR] MyClass.kt: (16, 19) Unresolved reference: functionName
[ERROR] MyClass.kt: (19, 28) Unresolved reference: SOME_FIELD
... etc.
```

Comment: What's the actual maven command you use and the actual output?

Comment: @tgdavies I have updated the question with the part that throws the error

Comment: Then the problem is not with maven finding the dependency, but the dependency not containing the symbols you expect.

Comment: @tgdavies but that only happens when the version for `project B` is specified as a property. If I put the actual string in there it works fine.

Comment: That is odd. Does mvn dependency:list show anything different?

Comment: can you. print the class-paths - for both successful  and failed builds - since they must be same - you will know the issue

Answer (score 0):

Maven cannot resolve artifact that were installed/deployed with a version from parameter.

In order for your artifacts to be resolvable after build, you will have to use [flatten-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/) so you get an effective pom which will be resolvable by maven.

You can see an example on how to do this in [maven-ci-friendly](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html#install-deploy)